# Если файлов в папке отстутсвуют завершить выполнение batch файла

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Как завершить выполнение скрипта если файлов в папке 0.

Comment: А в чем проблема-то?

Comment: Для этого надо сначала вопрос задать. А у вас, к слову, ни одного вопросительного знака.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте цикл `for` для перебора и подсчета файлов

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set cnt=0
for %%i in (%my_path%\*.*) do set /a cnt=!cnt! + 1
if %cnt%==0 goto :eof
echo "Found files"
```